# pyspark aggregating every n rows

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aggregation

I am trying  to create a new dataframe that has the averages of every 60 observations coming from the old dataframe. Here is the code I implemented in pandas:

```
new_df = old_df.groupby(old_df.index // 60).mean()
```

I am struggling with how to do this same thing in databricks using pyspark.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you have an index column in your dataframe you can do something similar as you proposed:

```
new_df=old_df.withColumn("new_index", col(index)/60).groupBy("new_index").agg(avg(YOUR_COLUMN_FOR_AVERAGE))
```

Best Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you already have an index column for which your dataframe should be ordered.
You can create a sequential [`row_number`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.row_number.html) and then use a trick with the [`floor`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.floor.html) function, which rounds down a decimal number.
`row_number` should be partitioned and ordered according to your columns of interest (partition columns is not necessary); they should define a group uniquely.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

everyN = 60
new_df = (old_df
  .withColumn('row_number', F.row_number().over(Window.partitionBy(...).orderBy(...)))
  .withColumn('group', F.floor((F.col('row_number') - 1) / everyN))
  .groupby('group')
  .agg(F.mean(<YOUR_COLUMN>))
)
```